# Requiring unknown module "react-native-safari-view" in Release mode

Tags: android, debugging, react-native, node-modules

I have a React Native project and it runs successfully on both simulators and devices for iOS.

However, for Android, it runs successfully on simulators without any problems, but when run on devices as a Release build, it gives me this error:

```
Requiring unknown module "react-native-safari-view".
```

I tried `npm cache clean` and `npm install` several times, but it does not work.

The module exists in `node_modules` folder and it is also under `dependencies` in `package.json`.

What could be the cause of this? Why does it happen only in Release builds?

**Update:** If this is difficult to fix, is it possible to generate a signed apk with the js bundle included in **dev mode**?

Comment: Is the package folder available inside node_modules folder?

Comment: @Sriraman Yes, it is.

Comment: In your `package.json` file does "react-native-safari-view" appear under `dependencies` or `devDependencies`?

Comment: @KyleFinley It appears under `dependencies`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `react-native-safari-view` module is not designed for Android.

Check this out: (inside [index.android.js](https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-safari-view/blob/master/index.android.js) file in [GitHub](https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-safari-view))

```
var SafariViewManager = {
  test: function() {
    warning('Not yet implemented for Android.');
  },
  isAvailable: function() {
    ...
  }
};
```

Maybe you are initiating a `SafariViewManager` object and calling other functions like `show()` in [index.ios.js](https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-safari-view/blob/master/index.ios.js) without checking it `isAvailable()`?

Comment: Exactly! Not calling `isAvailable()` before using `show()` resulted in the error in Android. Thanks so much!